# How do I display a username on their profile pages?

Tags: users

Using Drupal 8, I simply want a user's profile (or account) page to show its username, like so:

For username "bob":

Username: bob

Do I add a computed field? What's a line of code would I use?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I add a computed field?

No

> What's a line of code would I use?

In your theme's `.theme` file add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) { // your theme might already have this function/hook.
  $user = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('user');
  if ($user instanceof \Drupal\user\UserInterface) {
    $variables['title'] = t('Username') . ': ' . $user->getAccountName();
  }
}
```

<sub>Note: Clear/flush the cache for changes to kick in.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Didn't work though. I'm using Bartik. I copied it under where that first line is.

Comment: @nittyjee I assume you're using Bartik for quick testing purposes. You need to put it in `function bartik_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {` and don't forget to save the file and flush the cache.

Comment: Yeah, I did all that, I put it below that line and flushed all caches, still not appearing.

Comment: Here's a screenshot:
https://nahc-mapping.org/mappingNY/encyclopedia/temp_delete_anytime/Screenshot_1.jpg

Comment: Still not working :/
Screenshot:
https://nahc-mapping.org/mappingNY/encyclopedia/temp_delete_anytime/Screenshot_2.jpg

Comment: Saved, flushed cache? O_o

Comment: Yes. Saved and flushed :/

Comment: Hello world does appear.
I'll take a look in the next day, there may be something blocking it, I'll see how far I get.

Comment: @nittyjee try it on the actual theme you plan to use. You're not suppose to use Bartik anyways, nor touch anything inside the `/core` folder because you'll lose the changes every time you update core.